# CMD + = shortcut on non standard USA keyboard (bluetooth)?

Tags: keyboard, xcode, shortcut, internationalization

I need to execute a shortcut key of CMD + =, problem is that the = on my keyboard (non usa, european) it is obtained by pressing the Shift on the 0 (zero)  ...

So I tried doing CMD + Shift + 0 but this doesn't work, infact it does something completely different.

In xcode the shortcut is used to "Size to fit content"

Anyone know what the solution is ?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your custom keyboard shortcuts.

Adding a Custom Keyboard Shortcut Command Set

Personalize your Xcode experience by adding your own set of keyboard shortcuts. Xcode provides a default set of shortcuts for most menu commands and common text editing commands. Many of these default shortcuts are based on the commonly used Emacs key bindings.

```
In the Key Bindings preferences pane, choose Manage Key Bindings from the Key Bindings set pop-up menu.

Click the Add button in the lower left of the dialog.

Choose Duplicate or a template option from the pop-up menu.
Name your new command set file.
```

You can override the default shortcuts by creating a new command set with your preferred shortcuts. This new set is stored in the folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/ as a property list with the extension .idekeybindings.

<sub>source:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-keybindings_preferences/articles/AddingaCustomKeyboardShortcutCommandSet.html</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but apart from reconfiguring the key. It would be impossible on my keyboard to execute CMD + =  (as = requires the shift key) ?

Comment: as said, make a NEW shortcut for that function, obviously without the "=", and use something else.